# Submit form with image and text

Tags: html, image, input, submit, form-submit

So I have this code to make a submit button:

```
<a  style="text-decoration:none;height:42px;" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
    <input type="image" STYLE="width:152px;height:42px;" class="autosuggest" src="./images/images_25.png"/>
    <p style="position:relative;top:-55px;font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#FFFFFF;">Entrar</p>
</a>
```

I want to have a image with a text in the middle of it and when I click either the image or the text it submits the form. However, the `<p>` is somehow messing with the `<a>` and when I click `<p>` it does nothing. Only if i click the image the form is submited.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `<p>` outside of the `<a>`. Also, the input tag don't have to be inside the a because it already submits the form:

```
<input type="image" ... />
<p><a onclick="...">Entrar</a></p>
```